# Rollup ES6 access module in multiple bundles

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, rollup, rollupjs

How can I reuse code from another bundle so I don't end up bundling that code again? For example:

One.js

```
import $ from './jQuery';
import Something from './Something';
Something.do($('.test'));
```

After Rollup: bundleOne.js

```
(function () {
    var $ = function() { // ... }();
    var Something = function() { // ... }();
    Something.do($('.test'));
}());
```

Two.js

```
import $ from './jQuery';
$('.testTwo').addClass('test');
```

After Rollup: bundleTwo.js

```
(function () {
    var $ = function() { // ... }();
    $('.testTwo').addClass('test');
}());
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundleOne.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundleTwo.js"></script>
```

The above code causes Rollup to bundle jQuery twice. How can I access jQuery from bundleOne.js in bundleTwo.js and prevent Rollup from including jQuery in bundleTwo.js? There are multiple modules I'd like to reuse in the second bundle without including them again.

Comment: Add jQuery as external in the configuration of rollup for the second bundle